# Get posts from following Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I am building a social network where the user will have a stream like Twitter of all the posts from the people that they follow.

What is the best way to query this with Laravel Eloquent?

I have 3 tables

## users

`id | username | etc...|`

## relationships

`id | user_id |follows_id |`

## posts

`id | user_id | post|`

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like this (Basic Idea):

users

```
id | username | etc...
```

posts

```
id | user_id | post_content
```

favorites (relationships)

```
id | user_id |post_id
```

Define the Post class something like this:

```
class Post extends Eloquent {

    //...

    public function favorites()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Favorite');
    }

}
```

Define the favorite class:

```
class Favorite extends Eloquent {
    // ...
}
```

Query for the posts:

```
$posts = Post::whereHas('favorites', function($q) {
    $q->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id);
})->get();
```

Comment: Thanks @sheik but I'm not sure if this will work for what I'm trying to do.